# How to get the URL that the page is currently navigating to (Before navigation finishes)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

So I have a web browser I'm building on Windows Phone 8. Most web browsers I see, such as Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer, etc update the textbox displaying the URL while the page is loading. What I'm currently doing is updating it after the page is done loading. I can't find a way to do what IE is doing. The mobile version of IE on WP does indeed update the URL while the page is loading, but I can't figure out the code to do that.

My current code, which updates after the browser is done navigating:

```
 private void myWebBrowserControl_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        myProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Not related to this.
        myURLTextbox.Text = myWebBrowserControl.Source.ToString();
    }
```

I tried tossing the code into the myWebBrowserControl_Navigating, but got a run-time error. The reason I'm doing it is some sites redirect while still loading. For example, the site http://www.mmo-champion.com/ redirects to http://www.mmo-champion.com/content/. I want myURLTextbox.Text to recognize that the redirect is happening, so I'd prefer to update while navigating

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself in the depths of Google searching.

The solution would be to add the following code under myWebBrowserControl_Navigating:

```
private void myWebBrowserControl_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    { 
        myURLTextbox.text = e.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

I've removed the line of code I had added to myWebBrowserControl_Navigated as it is no longer necessary.